# All values are null when posting to controller in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, controller

When I insert values into view model and debug, all of the values are null in the controller, I have an 
`[HttpGet]
public IActionResult CreatePrescription(int id)` that gets the view model and then I have

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreatePrescription(ViewModel model){
        try
        {
            Prescription prescription = new Prescription
            {
                PatientId = model.Patient.Id,
                MedicationId = model.Prescription.MedicationId,
                RxNumber = model.Prescription.RxNumber,
                Frequency = model.Prescription.Frequency,
                Quantity = model.Prescription.Quantity,
                Copay = model.Prescription.Copay,
                RefillsRemaining = model.Prescription.RefillsRemaining,
                FolderStatusId = model.Prescription.FolderStatusId,
                PrescriberId = model.Prescription.PrescriberId,
                OriginalRxDate = model.Prescription.OriginalRxDate,
                DateFilled = model.Prescription.DateFilled,
                ExpiryDate = model.Prescription.ExpiryDate,
                DeliveryDate = model.Prescription.DeliveryDate,
                DeliveryTime = model.Prescription.DeliveryTime,
                BillDate = model.Prescription.BillDate,
                ApplicationUserId = user,
                CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,
                IsActive = true
            };

            _context.Add(prescription);

            _context.SaveChanges();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Here is part of the view

```
@model Systemz.Models.ViewModels.ViewModel
<div class="modal-body">
    <form asp-action="CreatePrescription" asp-controller="Patients" method="post">
        <input asp-for="Prescription.Id" type="hidden" />
        <input asp-for="Patient.Id" type="hidden" />
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <label asp-for="Prescription.RxNumber" class="custom-label"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <input asp-for="Prescription.RxNumber" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <span asp-validation-for="Prescription.RxNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <label asp-for="Prescription.Frequency" class="custom-label"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <input asp-for="Prescription.Frequency" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <span asp-validation-for="Prescription.Frequency" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <label asp-for="Prescription.Quantity" class="custom-label"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <input asp-for="Prescription.Quantity" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <span asp-validation-for="Prescription.Quantity" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And here is the class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace Systemz.Models,ViewModels
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public Prescription Prescription {get;set;}
        public IEnumerable<Prescription> Prescriptions {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Here is my db context

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Systemz.Models;

namespace Systemz.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
        {
        }

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> 
    options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Patient> Patients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Prescriber> Prescribers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Prescription> Prescriptions { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
         builder.Entity<PatientPrescriber>()
             .HasKey(bc => new { bc.PatientId, bc. PrescriberID });
         builder.Entity<PatientPrescriber>()
             .HasOne(bc => bc.Patient)
            .WithMany(b => b.PatientPrescribers)
            .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.PatientId);
        builder.Entity<PatientPrescriber>()
            .HasOne(bc => bc.Prescriber)
            .WithMany(c => c.PatientPrescribers)
            .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.PrescriberId);
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

All of the values that are in `IEnumerable<Prescription> Prescriptions {get;set;}` are in a class called Prescription, 
Here is the debug that shows a PatientId being accepted but all other properties are null
[PAtientId](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJyRm.png), and [Null Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HHme.png),
why are my values not being passed into the controller and not saving to the database?

Comment: try add FromForm .... CreatePrescription([FromForm] ViewModel model){

Comment: also your model missing `model.Patient.Id`

Comment: Make sure you not enabled camel casing. If that's the case, then post data using the camel cases.

Comment: @daremachine I tried adding a [FromForm] and did not help, also model.Patient.Id is fine, imagine adding a prescription to a patient, that is what I am doing, and `model.Patient.Id` is the only value that is getting passed

Comment: can you post your applicationContext

Comment: I don't see `ViewModel` have a property for `Patient`

Comment: @Clint Yes I am sorry, the `ViewModel` does have a property for `Patient`, I just didn't display the entire ViewModel, because it is pretty long, so I just displayed but I felt was necessary, I will show some of dbcontext as well

Comment: your ViewModel only has 2 properties `Prescription` & `Prescriptions` and nothing for `Patient`

Comment: @Clint my ViewModel is fine, it has all of the necessary properties in it, I just did not display the entire viewmodel because it would be a very long post as it contains a lot of properites.It contains `Patient` , and `Patient` is the only property that is not null

Comment: @Clint sorry that is not the solution I am looking for, I simply typed all of the code in the question insstead of copy and paste. So in my actual code I get no syntax errors from the `Systemz.Models,ViewModels`, I am just wondering why none all of the values are passing other than PatientId

Comment: @Clint Honestly I went back to previous git commit that was working and using ajax functions, and I just decdied to use that instead.

Comment: @Clint yes I believe it probably had to do with the ajax functions, which I did not create and I am not familiar with ajax whatsoever, but htanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the reason that it wasn't working is because the `View` only allows one `form` in it. I didn't know that it would only read the first `form` on my view, so problem solved. I had 
`<form asp-action="CreatePrescriber" asp-controller="Patients" method="Post">` and 
`<form asp-action="CreatePrescription" asp-controller="Patients" method="Post">`. It would take one `<form />` and stop reading after that.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the three observations I have made by reviewing portions of your code

- In your`Post` method of  `CreatePrescription`  its good practice to check `ModelState.IsValid`

  ```
   [HttpPost]
   public IActionResult CreatePrescription(ViewModel model){
   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
     try
     { Prescription prescription = new Prescription{ ....   } }
   }
  ```
- In your `Get` method of `CreatePrescription` make sure you're returning `model` to `View`.

  ```
   [HttpGet]
   public IActionResult CreatePrescription(int id)
   {
     //Any other business logic
      var model = new ViewModel();
      return View(model)
   }
  ```
- *Namespace* of your `ViewModel` class is defined as `Systemz.Models,ViewModels` with a comma and in Your View you have referred to it as `Systemz.Models.ViewModels.ViewModel`.